# Adding/improving guidance to the Survey tag

Tags: discussion

The [survey](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey) tag currently has no guidance, so it could be interpreted as ambiguous between

1. The type of survey where you ask people questions, which on Wikipedia is called [Survey (Human Research)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_(human_research)), and
2. The type of [surveying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveying) that involves making spatial measurements for the purpose of mapping features on the surface of the earth, eg, geological surveying, cadastral surveying, construction surveying, etc.

There are currently 16 questions with this tag, and they all refer to the first definition of survey. So I edited the survey tag information as follows ([changes pending peer review](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10862)):

*Usage guidance (excerpt):* `Use for questions about human research surveys.`

*Full tag Wiki:*

> In research of human subjects, a survey is a list of questions aimed at extracting specific data from a particular group of people. Surveys may be conducted by phone, mail, via the internet, and sometimes face-to-face on busy street corners or in malls. Surveys are used to increase knowledge in fields such as social research and demography. (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_(human_research)))

**Are these good changes? Could the `survey` tag wiki be improved more?**

Is the phrase "human research surveys" confusing? If so, what's a better way to phrase it?

I think it would be better if the excerpt said something like, "Use for questions about human research surveys. For questions about land surveying, use the `XXX` tag."

**What tag should people use for questions about land surveying?** (For example [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/15534/19566) about Public Land Survey System Data)

Comment: congrats on hitting 1k!

Answer (score 1):

> Are these good changes?

yes

> Could the survey tag wiki be improved more?

I guess there is always room for improvement, but slowly is OK, too.

> Is the phrase "human research surveys" confusing? If so, what's a better way to phrase it?

I would include some synonyms, like poll, study, probe, questionnaire, opinion poll, sampling, census, cross-examination, quiz, ...

> What tag should people use for questions about land surveying?

[geospatial](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial)?